# what are the advantages we get using JMS instead of using REST TEMPLATE for exchanging the information?

Tags: java, rest, jms

on my understandings,we use jms for exchanging the information between two or more systems,we can also use Rest Template for exchanging the information,but we use jms for exchanging the inforamtion,may i know what are the advantages we get using jms instead of using REST Template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Asynchronous** communications : An application need to notify another that an event has occurred with no need to wait for a response.
- **Reliability**. Ensure once-and-only-once message delivery. With your DB approach you have to "reinvent the wheel", specially if you have several clients reading the messages.
- **Loose coupling**.  Not all systems can communicate using a database.  So JMS is pretty good to be used in heterogeneous environments with decoupled systems that can communicate over system boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of advantages `JMS` brings into the table.

1. JMS allows fire-and-forget messages with guaranteed delivery.
2. JMS is useful for `asynchronous` request-reply messaging. Use them to process long-running operations asynchronously.However HTTP based models are `synchronous` and lead to fail fast approach.
3. Publish/subscribe is another good technique for decoupling senders from many receivers. It's a flexible architecture, because subscribers can come and go as needed.
4. Integration of disparate systems in a heterogeneous environment. Any kind of disparate systems that cannot talk to each other are decent candidates for [message-based] integration applications.

Due to the above advantages, JMS is heavily used in Enterprise Integration.